# Error installing pods with conflicting GoogleMLKit/FaceDetection dependencies in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, google-mlkit, podfile

I am encountering an issue while installing pods in my React Native project using CocoaPods. After executing pod install, I receive the following error:

> [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod
> "GoogleMLKit/FaceDetection":   In Podfile:
> react-native-face-detection (from `../node_modules/react-native-face-detection`) was resolved to 0.1.1,
> which depends on
> GoogleMLKit/FaceDetection (= 2.2.0)
>
> ```
> vision-camera-face-detector (from `../node_modules/vision-camera-face-detector`) was resolved to 0.1.8,
> ```
>
> which depends on
> GoogleMLKit/FaceDetection
>
> None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependencies:
> `GoogleMLKit/FaceDetection (= 2.2.0), GoogleMLKit/FaceDetection`.
>
> You have either:  * out-of-date source repos which you can update with
> `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.  * mistyped the
> name or version.  * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec
> to your Podfile.

It seems there is a conflict regarding the dependencies related to GoogleMLKit/FaceDetection. I have tried updating the pod repos using pod repo update and pod install --repo-update, but the issue persists.

Here is a snippet from my Podfile:

```
  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'

  pod 'rn-fetch-blob', :path => '../node_modules/rn-fetch-blob'

  pod 'RNFS', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fs'

  pod 'GoogleMLKit/FaceDetection', '2.2.0'
  pod 'GoogleMLKit/MLKitCore', '2.2.0'
  pod 'GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition', '2.6.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to delete the Pods and the Podfile.lock ?

cd ios => rm-rf Pods Podfile.lock => Pod install

Maybe this can help to fix, if not try to delete node_modules before and install all packages again, them delete Pods Podfile.lock and Pod install. I hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

1)remove the podfile
2)reset cache
3)restart metro bundler
4)try reinstalling pods again.
Also make sure you have recent updated version of cocoapods installed